# Reply for comment redirects to the next page

Tags: comments, nodes

I am using advance forum module and having commenting functionality for the forums. But the problem is when I use to reply to the comments it redirects me to the next page. Where I want to display a comment form exactly below to the comment to which I am replying. Where should I configure for this? With comment module or just with advance forum module?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan thanks, greetings etc should be removed totally, not formatted :)

Comment: Thanks @Mołot, yes generally I do so. That was a mistake. Anyway I'll be cautious . Thanks for the remind :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [AJAX Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module is what you're looking for.

I've installed it it's working good without Advanced Forum module.

> **Features:**
>
> Provides ajax comments to Drupal sites. Features:
>
> - Makes AJAX submits
> - Allows replies to comments on the actual thread page
> - AJAX comments deleting
> - Works with CAPTCHA
> - Cool jQuery sliding
> - views integration

Comment: I have installed and configured AJAX Comments but still its not working.

Comment: @D-pak What do mean 'not working'? It is still redirecting to next page?

Comment: Its not redirecting now , but after clicking on reply link its not displaying comment form (Text area ) and also hiding reply link.

Comment: @D-pak It's working fine from my end. Please check it once. Check console log

Comment: Error in console is that the 'coda' font is not being downloaded. But I don't think this affects for commenting system. Does it?

Comment: Any javascript error might break the execution of the rest of the javascript or AJAX on the page.